# Saving to text-File from serial (UART) STM32 with QT/C++

Tags: c++, qt, stm32

I'm trying to save a parameter from UART input to txt-File. Please help me to understand what is wrong! Parameter have a form from 0|0|0|0 to 999|999|999|999. Txt File "SAVE_DATA_LOG" stays empty. 
Why?

I'm  also trying  to get a system-timecode next to values - how can I get it?

I'm also sending a strings like "MP11500" (already works).

```
#include <UART_PC.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
//#include <ui_UART_PC.h>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>

using namespace std;

// ************************************************************************************************
UART_PC::UART_PC() {

    if (0 == connectSerial()) {
        qDebug() << "Serial Ok!\n";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Serial Error!\n";
        return;
    }

    m_state = WAIT; 

    m_timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processMeas()),Qt::QueuedConnection);
    //m_timer->setInterval(1000);
    m_timer->start(1000); //Timer 1 sec

    m_cnt = 0;

    m_values.setFileName(PWM_VALUES); //PWM - Values for motors
    m_values.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

     qDebug()<<"Start..";

QSerialPort *serialPort= new QSerialPort();

}

// ************************************************************************************************
UART_PC::~UART_PC() {

}

// ************************************************************************************************
uint32_t UART_PC::connectSerial(void) { //Serial init

    m_serial.setPortName(SDEV);
    m_serial.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    m_serial.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    m_serial.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    m_serial.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    m_serial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    if (!m_serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
        return 1;
    }

    connect(&m_serial, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readRequest()),Qt::QueuedConnection);

    return 0;
}


// ************************************************************************************************
void UART_PC::processMeas() { //State machine

    qDebug()<<"Tick:"<<m_cnt;

    if (m_state == WAIT) { //State 0 - Wait
        m_cnt++;
        if(m_cnt == 5){
            m_state = SET_V1;
        }
    }

    if (m_state == SET_V1) { //State 1 - Send
        if(m_values.atEnd()){
            m_values.seek(0);
        }
        if(!m_values.atEnd()){
            QString v = m_values.readLine();
            QStringList chunks = v.split(",");
            QString cmd = "MP"+chunks.at(0)+chunks.at(1)+"\n\0";
            m_serial.write(cmd.toUtf8());
            m_serial.waitForBytesWritten(1000);
//            qDebug()<<cmd<<v;
            m_cnt = 0;
            m_state = SET_V2;
//            m_state = WAIT;
        }

        if (m_state == SET_V2){ // State 2 - receive and write
            UART_PC::saveFile(QString::fromStdString(buffer.data()));

            m_state = WAIT;
        }

    }

}

// ************************************************************************************************
void UART_PC::readRequest() {  //Read and save
    QMutexLocker lock(&m_mutex_serial);
    m_serial_data += m_serial.readAll();
    qDebug() << hex << m_serial_data;
  UART_PC::saveFile(QString::fromStdString(m_serial_data.data()));
//    buffer = m_serial_data;
    m_serial_data.clear();
}

// ************************************************************************************************
void UART_PC::saveFile(QString buffer){ //Save
//    qDebug() << "Ohlolololo"+buffer;
    QString LOG_FILE = SAVE_DATA_LOG;
    QFile file(LOG_FILE);
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << buffer << endl;
    file.close();
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving the data?

Comment: Yes! Also, I get a qDebug output with right values ex. 5|0|0|0 but the textfile SAVE_DATA_LOG seems 0|0|0|0